# Is there any change made in the adsense conditions that it can not be applied for a free site?

Tags: google-adsense

Is there any policy change in google adsense which says that from now on only paid sites will be allowed to apply for adsense?like www.blabla.blogspot.com can not apply for a adsense account?
EDIT:
here's a link which says that:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=5e8e8313f54d1a6e&hl=en

Comment: 1) what do you mean by "paid sites"? 2) Where did you read this news?

Comment: I read that in a local website which teaches people how to do SEO etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's complete nonsense.

Comment: @listo:check out the edit.